# How to run program written for old compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I'm looking for an implementation of Hybrid Tree(not important), and find an "old" one [here](http://www-db.ics.uci.edu/pages/software/htree.shtml).

The author said they have tried this code on the SUN Sparc platform (running **Solaris 2.6**) and with **gcc-2.8.1** compiler. And my environment is **gcc version 4.4.3** (**Ubuntu 10.10**).

The problem is:
I run "make" with the makefile he provides, but it gives me lots of error message as follows:

```
g++  -c  Node.C
g++  -c  DataNode.C
In file included from DataNode.h:18,
                 from DataNode.C:17:
Query.h:9:20: error: vector.h: No such file or directory
Query.h:10:19: error: stack.h: No such file or directory
Query.h:13:22: error: function.h: No such file or directory
Query.h:14:22: error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
DataNode.C:283:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
In file included from DataNode.h:18,
                 from DataNode.C:17:
Query.h:29: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration
Query.h:44: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration
Query.h:86: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
Query.h:118: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘PQ’ with no type
Query.h:118: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
Query.h:122: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘PQ’ with no type
Query.h:122: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
Query.h:126: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘PQ’ with no type
Query.h:126: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
Query.h:135: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
DataNode.C: In member function ‘void DataNode::DisconnectBranch(int)’:
DataNode.C:80: error: ‘memmove’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [DataNode.o] Error 1
```

I know I need to modify the souce code so as to agree with the morden compiler, such as change `vector.h` to `vector`. But I find it's just endless.

So my question is: is there any convienent method to run this program, no matter automatically converting this code to "modern-style" or using a standalone "old-style" compiler ?

Any suggestions?

===**Update:**===

Thank you all, I installed gcc2.8.1 in a different dir using `--prefix=/usr/local/gcc-2.8.1` and modify the "makefile" to use this old-version gcc(`/usr/local/gcc-2.8.1/bin/gcc`). But when I run "make", it still gives me errors of not finding the headers:

```
/usr/local/gcc-2.8.1/bin/gcc  -c  DataNode.C
In file included from DataNode.h:18,
                 from DataNode.C:17:
Query.h:9: vector.h: No such file or directory
Query.h:10: stack.h: No such file or directory
Query.h:11: deque: No such file or directory
Query.h:12: algorithm: No such file or directory
Query.h:13: function.h: No such file or directory
Query.h:14: iostream.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [DataNode.o] Error 1
```

Then I tried to find these heads in /usr/local/gcc-2.8.1 using `find /usr/local/gcc-2.8.1 -name "*vector*"`, but got nothing.

So where are these heads for the old-version gcc?

Answer (score 8):

You can make a vertor.h yourself which includes vector. This way you can fix the incompatibilities noninvasively.

Edit:

You may also need to add a 
 `using namespace std;`
 in the header file(s). This is 
generally a bad idea but this is one situation where i'd do it anyway.

Once you get it working i would reccomend rewriting it to use the new style header files and namespaces.

Comment: Importing namespaces is a compiler thing, so no `#` in front of it!

Comment: Thanks. Will fix. I said my c++ was rusty.

Answer (score 3):

Debian Lenny (oldstable) has gcc 3.4. This might have a better backward compatibility. Try to make compatibility headers for the rest of the issues and include them via an extra `-I` directory, e.g. a `vector.h` header file that includes `vector`.

Do yourself the favor and try not to touch the old code. It is easy to break legacy code in unforeseen ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the program on QEMU which [supports Solaris 2.6](http://tyom.blogspot.com/2009/12/solaris-under-qemu-how-to.html). The only problem might be hunting for the install disc/image. Also, there are people that sells old Solaris boxes on eBay for cheap, you might be able to grab one.

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) provides download for very old versions, you might be able to get better chance if you try older version of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` has `-fpermissive` option: try it and see whether at least some errors disappear. Also: try making a single header file that will include *all* requisite headers with using directives.  For example, make `stdinc.h` containing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
...

using std::vector;
using std::fstream;
...
```

Replace all mentions of legacy C++ header files with a single include of `stdinc.h`.  Old C++ didn't have namespaces, so even if you replace individual directives with just `using namespace std;`, clashes are unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing is

```
#include <vector.h>
```

to

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

Why not try sed?

grep for all includes to see if there are other includes than the c++ headers. If not your lucky.

Another thing that is more tricky is that there is old code that relies on accessing data through iterators in a non-standard way. I saw that in a Doom map editor for linux. Then you may need to do manual stuff.